# Hide Hightlighted Border in Telerik RadMenuComboItem

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, telerik

i want to hide the following blue border:

[image]

At startup it looks like this:

[image]

and after slided over with mouse, it gets the blue border which i am not able to disable. 
I do not find the right property, maybe someone can help me.

Regards,

Hendrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the provided information, it seems that you are using the Fluent theme. The following code snippet demonstrates how to eliminate the blue border:

`BorderPrimitive b = this.radMenuComboItem1.ComboBoxElement.FindDescendant<BorderPrimitive>();
 b.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;`

I hope this helps